# How to send push notification with a button press using flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, button, push-notification

Can someone help me?
I want to notify all the users who installed my app. I was going to firebase cloud messaging and I am pushing a notification from there. But I want to create a button that collects the information from my textfield and push a notification to all the users.
I have been trying this for 24+ hours but I have found no solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I find one solution for this issue

You need to:

- Get an server API key from the firebase console.
- Create local Api service sent web key as authentication.
- Use (User token) to send notification on specific devices. Need to add notification data as raw data will work.

[Add web key in authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtzsT.png)

[Add notifcation data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAs5M.png)

[Add sender data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuNtE.png)

Click [This link to check detailed solution](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/android-firebase-push-notification/)!